# CodeIgniter4 - Creating Model for master table and details table

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller, crud, codeigniter-4

Am using CodeIgniter v4.3.2 and trying to learn the CRUD & MVC. I have two tables. One is the master table that stores details about the `ORDER` and another table called `ORDER DETAILS` that stores details about the order (like products).

I have created the model for the master table like this (`/app/Models/OrderModel.php`):

```
<?php 

namespace App\Models;  
use CodeIgniter\Model;

  
class OrderModel extends Model{

    protected $table = 'orders';
    
    protected $allowedFields = [
        'order_id',
        'order_date',
        'total_amount',
        'customer_id',
        'created_at'
    ];
}
```

So for the ORDER DETAILS, should I create the `order_details` as a separate Model (`OrderDetailsModel`)? Or is there a way I could use the same within the `OrderModel`.

Am trying to figure out what to be followed on this particular scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can do both. You can create a Model which can access all db-tables (`$this->db->table('ORDER DETAILS')->...`), **but** i would suggest that you create a new model for each table, so that you can use CI4's special capabilities like allowed-fields, callbacks and use-timestamps.